# Bird species ID in the Northern Territory, Australia

Tags: zoology, species-identification, ornithology

I was visiting [Darwin, NT, Australia](http://www.australia.com/en/places/darwin.html) a few years back and I encountered this bird. I must say it was in [Darwin's Botanical Gardens](https://nt.gov.au/leisure/parks-reserves/george-brown-darwin-botanic-gardens), so I can't be absolutely positive the Northern Territory is its original habitat. However, I'm pretty sure it's a NT native, as the whole Gardens were packed with, and dedicated to NT's wildlife.

[image: Bird]

The photo is kind of dark and a bit fuzzy due to poor lighting conditions. I already tried to digitally enhance it by removing shadows and so forth.

I tried Google Images reverse search to ID this bird, but I'm not a hero with that tool. Although it looks a bit like it - it's definitely not a [Jabiru](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b5/Jabiru_Perth_Zoo_Sept_2005.jpg/170px-Jabiru_Perth_Zoo_Sept_2005.jpg).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an **Australian White Ibis** (*Threskiornis moluccus*).

[image: Threskiornis moluccus]

It's [widespread](http://www.hbw.com/species/australian-ibis-threskiornis-moluccus) across much of Australia:

[image: Threskiornis moluccus rangemap]

You can find more info on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_white_ibis).

Comment: Can't accept it yet due to system limitations -- but *wow* that *is* quick - thanks!

Comment: I was just in Australia this year, so I recognized the species fairly quickly. "A Pocket Naturalist Guide: Australia Birds" was a useful tool while I was there.

Comment: Oh thanks for that pic of Oz - I was already wondering whether it truly was native in SE and NT - it's a big country!