# Which bird is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

Found this today in my neighborhood, my mom says it's a baby vulture and she has seen many during her childhood (in 1970's) while she lived in a small town around 200kms away from our city. However I want to know of it is really vulture cause there are less than 1000 left in whole state and certainly they don't usually fly around here. Even Monkeys (which are, FYI, common in India in small cities and are not afraid by humans) are mad because of this bird's presence but perhaps too frightened to go near him/her. It'd be nice if you guys can tell me what it is :).

[image]

I live in Gujarat, India if it helps.

Comment: See a very similar ibis species form Australia here: [Bird species ID in the Northern Territory, Australia](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/55945/16866)

Comment: @theforestecologist Yeah, ty for the info, good to know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks a lot like a [*African sacred ibis* (*Threskiornis aethiopicus*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_sacred_ibis) (wikilink). However, given your location in India, the closely related [*Black-headed ibis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-headed_ibis) (which some consider to be part of the same species) might be more likely.

The *African sacred ibis* is native to mainly sub-saharan Africa, but is considered Invasive in some parts of the world (inkl. Europe and parts of Asia). The *Black-headed ibis* is however a native breeding bird to large parts of Asia (inkl. India), which makes this more likely.

[image]
(*Black-headed ibis* from wikipedia)

Comment: Yesss! I was just googling using features and found this bird and then at the same time saw yr answer, I'm quite certain now after your answer that this is it! Thanks a lot